# Convert 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm-offset' format to 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm' in moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to convert from UTC time to user's timezone.

What is happening is that:

```
let con = this.$rootScope.mtz.tz(utcTime, timeZoneInfo.usersTimeZone).local().format();
```

will return me something like this: `2016-11-09T14:00-05:00 (client is UTC-5)`.

Result is correct, but how can I get the local date-time instead of an offset value?

Instead of this: `2016-11-09T14:00-05:00`, I want this: `2016-11-09 09:00`?

When I do this:

```
let con = this.$rootScope.mtz.tz(utcTime, timeZoneInfo.usersTimeZone).local().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

What I get for result is: `2016-11-09 14:00`.

It applies format, but does not convert to the local time zone.

Comment: what you have is correct 2016-11-09 14:00. the offset is not part of the local time, its just the offset from UTC. Add that offset to local time you will get UTC. Not sure why you want to decrease it by offset value.

Answer (score 0):

use the [`utc()` function provided by MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use
>   moment.utc() instead of moment().

So you can change your code and substitute the call to `local()` with `utc()`:

```
let con = this.$rootScope.mtz.tz(utcTime, timeZoneInfo.usersTimeZone).utc().format();
```